# What advantage does using a framework like CodeIgniter or CakePHP provide over using 'plain vanilla' PHP?

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm new to PHP and am trying to more of an overview before I jump into the code sometime tomorrow.

What advantage does using a framework like CodeIgniter or CakePHP or Zend provide over using 'plain vanilla' PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851920/why-use-a-framework-with-php covers this pretty well. There are many more if you search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To use a PHP framework or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817096/to-use-a-php-framework-or-not)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972943/web-apps-to-framework-or-not-to-framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The framework takes care of the stuff that everyone's done a hundred times - authenticating users, talking to databases, handling file uploads, validating forms.
- It saves you time, because you don't have to write it again.
- It saves you headaches, because it's probably designed better than you would off the cuff and because it's already been thoroughly debugged.
- It makes it easier to collaborate, because anyone who knows the framework has a step up on understanding your program.
- It makes programming more fun, because you can focus on writing the interesting bits, not the slugwork.

Answer (score 1):

Any framework has the advantage of solving problems that just about any programmer would encounter without using a framework.

There are many common problems that you and I would face regardless of whether or not we're building software for banking, media, news, etc, and instead of reinventing the wheel, you can springboard off of the hundreds and thousands of hours of developer experience by using code that has been tried and tested in a multitude of different production environments.

The motto is this:  Don't reinvent the wheel.  Your job is to meet a business goal, not solve problems that other people have already solved for you.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage is: Design decisions are made for you.

Answer (score 0):

One disadvantage is: Design decisions are made for you.