# What are the advantages of a php framework like codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

What would be the advantage of using a framework like codeigniter vs raw PHP?

Comment: [Here is a good list of advantages.](http://bit.ly/1qqqXcV)

Comment: Sorry, I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576806/what-advantage-does-using-a-framework-like-codeigniter-or-cakephp-provide-over-u @NathanaelShermett. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. MVC pattern, which I recommend you read about. It provides concern separation and is an industry standard for building web apps.
2. Less boilerplate code - everything (mostly) you need is already provided by framework classes API
3. Active Record - a nicer way to query database
4. etc. Bottom line is - use a framework, unless it's a quick hack, then framework might be an overkill